# How to shrink the .git folder

Tags: git

My current base has a total size of approx. 200MB.

But my .git folder has an amazing size of 5GB (!). Since I push my work to an external server, i don't need any big local history...

How can I shrink the .git folder to free up some space on my notebook? Can I delete all changes that are older, than 30 days?

Comment: Can you post the output of `git count-objects -v` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce git repository size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size)

Comment: My problem was `git lfs` was taking up tons of space in the `.git/lfs` dir. By running `git lfs prune` I reduced my `.git` folder size by **>60 GB**! I added this information and more [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554906/4561887).

Comment: The answer of @GabrielStaples by default will delete files older than 3 days. To delete all large files including recent ones add the **-f** parameter

Comment: @Enos, in [my answer you are referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554906/4561887), which command exactly needs the `-f` argument?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I was referring to "git lfs prune". Your answer was correct but by default it does not prune files more recent than the configuration options (three days by default). For pruning all files including recent ones it needs the --force or --recent argument.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Linus Torvalds [recommends](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2007-12/msg00165.html):

```
git repack -a -d -f --depth=250 --window=250
```

This could take a long time for old repos. Consider letting it run overnight.

Note: Do you have a lot of binary files (archives, images, executables) which change often? Those usually lead to huge `.git` folders (remember, Git stores snapshots for each revision and binary files compress badly).

---

You should not delete all changes older than 30 days (I think it's somehow possible exploiting Git, but really not recommended).

Avoid running `git gc --aggressive --prune`, which performs garbage collection in the repository and prunes old objects. This method is considered bad practice.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: @Harry you have to be a lot more specific with your comment. The question was "how to shrink the .git folder" and this answer tells you how to "shrink it". It shrinks the git folder (by repacking the object files and garbage collecting unreachable/dangling objects)

Comment: Thanks. This was the part I was looking for: `repacking the object files and garbage collecting unreachable/dangling objects`.

Comment: @Harry The man pages of both commands have all the details

Comment: What if I just delete .git\objects\pack folder from build server ?
The size of above folder in my case is 176 GB

Comment: @Sagar Then your object database will become corrupted and you can no longer use your repository, because it is missing all the important data. Do **NOT** delete files from the .git directory tree!

Comment: @knittl : I am talking about "work\8\SourceDirectory" folder which is being used at the time of Azure CI ( build ) , i think it will always recreate this folder

Answer (score 122):

Here is what the creator of git [Linus](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2007-12/msg00165.html) has to say about how to shrink your git repo:

> The equivalent of "git gc --aggressive" - but done *properly* - is to 
>   do (overnight) something like
>
> ```
>    git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
> ```
>
> where that depth thing is just about how deep the delta chains can be 
>   (make them longer for old history - it's worth the space overhead), and 
>   the window thing is about how big an object window we want each delta 
>   candidate to scan.
>
> And here, you might well want to add the "-f" flag (which is the "drop all 
>   old deltas", since you now are actually trying to make sure that this one 
>   actually finds good candidates.

source: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2007-12/msg00165.html

**Will this get rid of binary data that is orphaned in my repo?** "git repack" will not git rid of images or binary data that you have checked into your repo and then deleted it. To delete those kind of data permanently from your repo you have to re-write your history. A common example of that is when you accidentally check in your passwords in git. You can go back and delete some files but then you have to re-write your history from then to now and then force push then new repo to your origin.

Comment: For me, .git folder is about 1.5G. I tried this, but I got followng error.

`fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 39763130 bytes)`

Comment: After executing `repack` locally, doing a commit and push, will the shrink be made remote also?

Comment: @David Dehghan: Hey I tried this from the project directory but the size of .git folder didn't change. Is this expected, or I need to push to see the changes? (sorry not very experienced with git.) I have an image/gif in repo and I committed several times different versions of that image and I suppose that increased .git size.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that is now how you clean up old binary version. To do that you need to re-write your history which is actually complicated. Here is some lead for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/remove-binaries?view=vsts

Comment: Didn't help. I had repo of 6G and it remained 6G after this command.

Answer (score 64):

I tried these but my repository was still very large. The problem was I had accidentally checked in some generated large files. After some searching I found a great tutorial which makes it easy to delete the large generated files. This tutorial allowed me to shrink my repository from 60 MB to < 1 MB.

> [Steve Lorek, *How to Shrink a Git Repository*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190207210108/http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html)

Updated: Here's a copy-paste version of the blog post.

## How to Shrink a Git Repository

Our main Git repository had suddenly ballooned in size. It had grown overnight to 180MB (compressed) and was taking forever to clone.

The reason was obvious; somebody, somewhere, somewhen, somehow, had committed some massive files. But we had no idea what those files where.

After a few hours of trial, error and research, I was able to nail down a process to:

- Discover the large files
- Clean them from the repository
- Modify the remote (GitHub) repository so that the files are never downloaded again

This process should never be attempted unless you can guarantee that all team members can produce a fresh clone. It involves altering the history and requires anyone who is contributing to the repository to pull down the newly cleaned repository before they push anything to it.

## Deep Clone the Repository

If you don't already have a local clone of the repository in question, create one now:

```
git clone remote-url
```

Now—you may have cloned the repository, but you don't have all of the remote branches. This is imperative to ensure a proper 'deep clean'. To do this, we'll need a little Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do
    git branch --track ${branch##*/} $branch
done
```

Thanks to [bigfish](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754797/513422) on StackOverflow for this script, which is copied verbatim.

Copy this code into a file, `chmod +x filename.sh`, and then execute it with `./filename.sh`. You will now have all of the remote branches as well (it's a shame Git doesn't provide this functionality).

## Discovering the large files

Credit is due to [Antony Stubbs here](http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/) - his Bash script identifies the largest files in a local Git repository, and is reproduced verbatim below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x 

# Shows you the largest objects in your repo's pack file.
# Written for osx.
#
# @see http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/
# @author Antony Stubbs

# set the internal field spereator to line break, so that we can iterate easily over the verify-pack output
IFS=$'\n';

# list all objects including their size, sort by size, take top 10
objects=`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head`

echo "All sizes are in kB. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file."

output="size,pack,SHA,location"
for y in $objects
do
    # extract the size in bytes
    size=$((`echo $y | cut -f 5 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the compressed size in bytes
    compressedSize=$((`echo $y | cut -f 6 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the SHA
    sha=`echo $y | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    # find the objects location in the repository tree
    other=`git rev-list --all --objects | grep $sha`
    #lineBreak=`echo -e "\n"`
    output="${output}\n${size},${compressedSize},${other}"
done

echo -e $output | column -t -s ', '
```

Execute this script as before, and you'll see some output similar to the below:

```
All sizes are in kB. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file.

size     pack    SHA                                       location
1111686  132987  a561d25105c79aa4921fb742745de0e791483afa  08-05-2012.sql
5002     392     e501b79448b9e970ab89b048b3218c2853fdfc88  foo.sql
266      249     73fa731bb90b04dcf79eeea8fdd637ba7df4c089  app/assets/images/fw/iphone.fw.png
265      43      939b31c563bd40b1ca70e4f4a9f7d67c27c936c0  doc/models_complete.svg
247      39      03514d9e84418573f26b205bae7e4e57057c036f  unprocessed_email_replies.sql
193      49      6e601c4067aaddb26991c4bd5fbddef003800e70  public/assets/jquery-ui.min-0424e108178defa1cc794ee24fc92d24.js
178      30      c014b20b6fed9f17a0b2809ac410d74f291da26e  foo.sql
158      158     15f9e56bc0865f4f303deff053e21909661a716b  app/assets/images/iphone.png
103      36      3135e15c5cec75a4c85a0636b154b83221020c97  public/assets/application-c65733a4a64a1a885b1c32694574b12a.js
99       85      c1c80bc4c09e692d5e2127e39c87ecacdb1e816f  app/assets/images/fw/lovethis_logo_sprint.fw.png
```

Yep - looks like someone has been pushing some rather unnecessary files somewhere! Including a lovely 1.1GB present in the form of a SQL dump file.

## Cleaning the files

Cleaning the file will take a while, depending on how busy your repository has been. You just need one command to begin the process:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' --prune-empty -f -- --all
```

This command is adapted from other sources—the principal addition is `--tag-name-filter cat` which ensures tags are rewritten as well.

After this command has finished executing, your repository should now be cleaned, with all branches and tags in tact.
Reclaim space

While we may have rewritten the history of the repository, those files still exist in there, stealing disk space and generally making a nuisance of themselves. Let's nuke the bastards:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

git gc --prune=now

git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Now we have a fresh, clean repository. In my case, it went from 180MB to 7MB.

## Push the cleaned repository

Now we need to push the changes back to the remote repository, so that nobody else will suffer the pain of a 180MB download.

```
git push origin --force --all
```

The `--all` argument pushes all your branches as well. That's why we needed to clone them at the start of the process.

Then push the newly-rewritten tags:

```
git push origin --force --tags
```

## Tell your teammates

Anyone else with a local clone of the repository will need to either use `git rebase`, or create a fresh clone, otherwise when they push again, those files are going to get pushed along with it and the repository will be reset to the state it was in before.

Comment: [Here's an archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20180112163756/http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html) in case of link rot. This answer is/was helpful for a repo I came across where .exe and .zip files were committed which bloated the size of .git folder

Comment: Any ideas why this would not work? The same large files exist after following all these steps. After the first clean command (git filter-branch...) there is a warning for each branch saying it was unchanged. I am using Git bash for windows if that matters.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this on my repo and the repo size seems to have reduced and it is evident too that git clone is much faster now. However, in my gitlab repo webpage, the size against Storage still shows bigger as previously. 

1
 Commit
2
 Branches
2
 Tags
203.9 MB
 Files
203.9 MB
 Storage
2
 Releases

Comment: `git-filter-branch` throws a warning: 
`git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo' (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.`

Comment: Use double quotes for `git filter-branch` in case of `fatal: bad revision 'rm'` on Windows.

Comment: @dpoiesz i assume you have to `git rm` the offending files and `git commit` at the end of the "Discovering the large files" step.

Answer (score 20):

### How to shrink your .git folder in your git repo

### First try this

If you have a lot of *duplicate data*, try running `git gc`. It has the potential to save a lot of space when you have tons of duplicate copies of the same or similar files. See here: [Does git de-duplicate between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662262/4561887), and [my answer and anecdotal experience on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682079/4561887), where `git gc` automatically compressed a whopping 107 GB down to 11 GB.

### Summary

Do, in this order, from least-dangerous and/or most-effective and/or fastest to more-dangerous and/or less-effective and/or slowest.

Note that the `git lfs` lines only apply if you have `git lfs` installed. Google for it and you'll see it's a 3rd party stand-alone application. If you don't have `git lfs` installed, just ignore those lines. See my comments below this answer, [starting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder/68554906?noredirect=1#comment129103874_68554906). Also, if you don't use `git lfs`, *don't.* It has the potential to cause many problems. I talk about it in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946411/4561887), for instance.

*These test results are for a repo where `du -hs --exclude=.git .` shows that the total repo size, NOT including the `.git` dir, is about **80 GB**, and `du -hs .git` showed that the `.git` folder **alone** started out at about **162 GB**:*

Update: definitely *do* run `time git gc`! It can have a *huge* space savings in cases where text files are largely duplicated. See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684971/4561887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682079/4561887).

```bash
#                                                                   Memory Saved
#                                               Time it took        in .git dir
#                                               ------------        ------------
time git lfs prune                              #  1~60 min          62 GB
time git gc                                     #  3 min            < 1 GB
time git prune                                  #  1 min            < 1 GB
time git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250  #  2 min            < 1 GB
# (Note: `--prune` does nothing extra here; `man git gc` says 
# `--prune is on by default`)
time git gc --aggressive --prune                #  1.25 hrs         < 1 GB
```

As you can see, the last command takes a *very* long time for very little benefit, so don't even run it!

Also, an alternative to running `git lfs prune` is to just delete the whole `.git/lfs` directory manually instead, then re-fetch the lfs (git Large File System) contents from scratch after.
**CAUTION: do NOT accidentally delete the whole `.git` directory instead! YOU'LL LOSE ALL GIT HISTORY, BRANCHES, AND COMMITS FOR THIS REPO!** Delete only the `.git/lfs` directory. Something like this might work:

```bash
# 1. Delete the whole git lfs directory
rm -rf .git/lfs


# 2. Re-fetch the git lfs contents again from scratch.
# See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610495/4561887

# Option 1 (recommended): fetch (to the ".git/lfs" dir) AND check out just the
# git lfs files for just the one branch or commit you currently have
# checked-out. 
# - this might download ~20 GB of data on a large corporate mono-repo
git lfs pull
# OR do this (these two commands do the exact same thing as `git lfs pull`)
git lfs fetch
git lfs checkout

# Option 2: fetch (to the ".git/lfs" dir) ALL git lfs files for ALL branches on
# the remote
# - this might download ~1000 GB of data on the same large corporate mono-repo
#   as above
git lfs fetch --all
# Also check out, or "activate" the git lfs files for your currently-checked-out
# branch or commit, by updating all file placeholders or pointers in your
# active filesystem for the current branch with the actual files these git lfs
# placeholders point to.
git lfs checkout
```

For details on the `git lfs` commands shown just above, see my other answer here: [How to use `git lfs` as a basic user: What is the difference between `git lfs fetch`, `git lfs fetch --all`, `git lfs pull`, and `git lfs checkout`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610495/4561887)

### Details

First off, you need to know what in the .git folder is taking up so much space. One technique is to run the ncurses-based (GUI-like) `ncdu` (NCurses Disk Usage) command inside your repo. Another way is to run this:

```bash
du -h --max-depth=1 .git
```

*Side note:* To see how big your repo is, NOT including your `.git` folder, run this instead:

```bash
du -h --max-depth=1 --exclude=.git .
```

Sample output of the 1st command above:

```bash
$ du -h --max-depth=1 .git
158G    .git/lfs
6.2M    .git/refs
4.0K    .git/branches
2.5M    .git/info
3.7G    .git/objects
6.2M    .git/logs
68K .git/hooks
162G    .git
```

As you can see, my total `.git` folder size is **162 GB**, but **158 GB** of that is my `.git/lfs` folder since I am using the 3rd-party "[Git Large File Storage" (`git lfs`)](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs) tool to store large binary files. So, run this to reduce that *significantly*. Note: the `time` part of all commands below is optional:

```bash
time git lfs prune
```

*(If `git lfs prune` fails with "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference", see my notes below.)*

Source: [How to shrink a git LFS repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680238/how-to-shrink-a-git-lfs-repo/59680272#59680272)
Official documentation: [`git-lfs-prune(1)` -- Delete old LFS files from local storage](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn)

That took *60 seconds* to run!

Now I've just freed up **62 GB!** My `.git/lfs` folder is now only **96 GB**, as shown here:

```bash
$ du -h --max-depth=1 .git
96G .git/lfs
6.2M    .git/refs
4.0K    .git/branches
2.5M    .git/info
3.0G    .git/objects
6.2M    .git/logs
68K .git/hooks
99G .git
```

Next, run this to shrink the `.git/objects` folder by a few hundred MB to ~1 GB or so:

```bash
time git gc
time git prune
```

`git gc` takes about 3 minutes to run, and `git prune` takes about 1 minute.

Check your disk usage again with `du -h --max-depth=1 .git`. If you'd like to save even more space, run this:

```bash
time git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

That takes about 2 minutes and saves a few hundred more MB.

Now, you can stop here, OR you can run this final command:

```bash
time git gc --aggressive --prune
```

That final command will save a few hundred more MB but will take about 1.25 hours.

### If `git lfs prune` fails with "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

If `git lfs prune` fails with:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

then you may have an old version of `git-lfs` installed and need to update it. Here is how:

First, check to see what version you have installed. Run `man git-lfs` and scroll to the bottom to see the date. Maybe it says it is from 2017, for instance. Now, update your version with these commands. The first command comes from here: https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install.

```bash
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git-lfs
```

Run `man git-lfs` again and scroll to the bottom. I now see my date as "March 2021", when previously it was some date in 2017.

Also, if I run `sudo apt install git-lfs` again, it tells me:

> git-lfs is already the newest version (2.13.3).

So, the update for `git-lfs` worked, and now the error is gone and `git lfs prune` works again!

I first documented this in a comment on GitHub here: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3395#issuecomment-889393444.

### References:

1. @knittl: [How to shrink the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder/5613380#5613380)
2. @David Dehghan: [How to shrink the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder/8483112#8483112)
3. `git lfs prune`: [How to shrink a git LFS repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680238/how-to-shrink-a-git-lfs-repo/59680272#59680272)
4. Linus Torvalds on `git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250`: https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2007-12/msg00165.html
5. https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn

### See also:

1. [Does git de-duplicate between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662262/4561887)
2. My Q&A: [How does git LFS track and store binary data more efficiently than git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567696/4561887)
3. My answer: [Unix & Linux: All about finding, filtering, and sorting with `find`, based on file size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731663/114401) - see the example near the end, titled **"(Figure out which file extensions to add to `git lfs` next)"**.
4. Other **really useful** `git lfs` info:

   1. Great article!: [my developer planet: Git LFS: Why and how to use](https://mydeveloperplanet.com/2018/10/31/git-lfs-why-and-how-to-use/)
   2. https://git-lfs.github.com/
   3. My repo and notes: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles#how-to-clone-this-repo-and-all-git-submodules
   4. ***** [my Q&A] [How to use `git lfs` as a basic user: What is the difference between `git lfs fetch`, `git lfs fetch --all`, `git lfs pull`, and `git lfs checkout`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610495/4561887)
5. [my Q&A] [How to resume `git lfs post-checkout` hook after failed `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552775/how-to-resume-git-lfs-post-checkout-hook-after-failed-git-checkout/68555047#68555047)
6. Note: for pure synchronization, try FreeFileSync or `rsync`, [as I explain in my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1271882/convert-ntfs-partition-to-ext4-how-to-copy-the-data/1464264#1464264). That being said, occasionally I use `git` for synchronization too, [as I explain for my `sync_git_repo_from_pc1_to_pc2.sh` tool here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/README_git-sync_repo_from_pc1_to_pc2.md), and in my other answer here: [Work on a remote project with Eclipse via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315754/4561887).
7. ***** My answer: [What are the file limits in Git (number and size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684971/4561887)
8. ***** My answer: [Does git de-duplicate between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682079/4561887)

Comment: Could any problems arise if you remove the .git/lfs folder without fetching afterwards?

Comment: @Showdown, it depends on what you have (or the repo owner has) stored by `git lfs`. Perhaps it contains some pre-compiled binaries that you don't need, or some photos to show how to build something (if the git repo is a set of instructions or a mechanical or KiCad model), or maybe it has PDF docs, etc. Only you can know that based on your particular repo. It won't hurt anything to delete `.git/lfs`. You can always just fetch or pull it if it is needed. If it contains necessary build content to build your program, it may affect the build. Run `git lfs ls-files` to see what it is tracking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I misunderstood how git works, but shouldn't the current state _outside_ the .git folder be a complete state with all necessary files anyway? So only meta-data, commit history, temp files etc. are found inside of it, i.e. nothing that affects my work with the current state until I want to reset/revert/pull/push?

Comment: @Showdown, `shouldn't the current state outside the .git folder be a complete state with all necessary files anyway?`--Yes, as far as I know, so long as you are also already checked-out on the branch or commit hash you want, *and* have already run `git lfs pull` to update `git lfs` file pointers to actually become the thing they point to. Otherwise, you'll just have text file ptrs (text files with hash strings in them) in place of the thing they point to.

Comment: I _think_ the `.git/lfs` dir contains copies of all _actual content_ of `git lfs` files you need for any `git lfs pull` you've already done on your git commits.

Comment: Is this answer out of date? I'm running `git version 2.34.1` and `git lfs prune` returns `git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @MRule, no, it's not out of date. Rather, the `git lfs` lines only apply if you have `git lfs` installed. Google for it and you'll see it's a 3rd party stand-alone application. If you don't have `git lfs` installed, just ignore those lines.

Comment: @MRule, as a side note, you can make your own `git anything` command simply by creating a script in any language named `git-anything`, marking it executable, and then putting it in any folder in your PATH. Now, typing `git anything` will cause `git` to search for the `git-anything` executable in your PATH and run it if it exists. That's how 3rd party applications can add their own `git` commands. I have added several custom `git` commands here, for instance: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/useful_scripts

Answer (score 12):

5GB vs 200MB is kind of weird. Try to run `git gc`.

But no, unless you split your repository into modules, you can't decrease the size of the `.git` directory.

Each clone of a git repo is a full fledged repository that can act as a server. That's the base principle of distributed version control.

Answer (score 8):

> Shrink a Git Repository by removing some files log history from the `.git` Folder based on their last updated time.

I had faced the same issue on my Local Machine. The reason was I have deleted some massive files from my local and committed to Central Repository. But event after `git status`, `git fetch` and `git pull`. My `.git` folder size is about 3GB. later I ran the following command to reduce the size of the `.git` folder by considering the files which have changed/expired a month ago.

Command

```
$ git remote prune origin && git repack && git prune-packed && git reflog expire --expire=1.month.ago && git gc --aggressive
```

[**`Git`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) Commands and their short description:

- `git-prune` - Prune all unreachable objects from the object database
- [`git-repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) - Pack unpacked objects in a repository
- [`git-prune-packed`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune-packed) - Remove extra objects that are already in pack files.
- [**`git reflog`**](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog): Git keeps track of updates to the tip of branches using a mechanism called reference logs, or "reflogs." Reflogs track when Git refs were updated in the local repository. In addition to branch tip reflogs, a special reflog is maintained for the Git stash. Reflogs are stored in directories under the local repository's `.git` directory. git reflog directories can be found at `.git/logs/refs/heads/.`, `.git/logs/HEAD`, and also `.git/logs/refs/stash` if the git stash has been used on the repo. git reflog at a high level on the [`Rewriting History`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history) Page.

   `git reflog expire --expire=now --expire-unreachable=now --all`

   In addition to preserving history in the reflog, Git has internal expiration dates on when it will prune detached commits. Again, these are all implementation details that `git gc` handles and `git prune` should not be used standalone.
- `git gc --aggressive`: [**git-gc**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) - Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository.
  Behind the scenes git gc actually executes a bundle of other internal subcommands like `git prune, git repack, git pack and git rerere`. The high-level responsibility of these commands is to identify any Git objects that are outside the threshold levels set from the `git gc` configuration. Once identified, these objects are then compressed, or pruned accordingly.

Commonad with Outcome:

```
$ git remote prune origin && git repack && git prune-packed && git reflog expire --expire=1.month.ago && git gc --aggressive
Enumerating objects: 535, done.
Counting objects: 100% (340/340), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (263/263), done.
Writing objects: 100% (340/340), done.
Total 340 (delta 104), reused 0 (delta 0)
Enumerating objects: 904, done.
Counting objects: 100% (904/904), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (771/771), done.
Writing objects: 100% (904/904), done.
Total 904 (delta 343), reused 561 (delta 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using git more as synchronization mechanism than for version history.  So my solution to this problem has been to make sure I have all my current sources in a satisfactory state, and then just delete .git and re-initialize the repos.  Disk space problem solved. :-)  History gone :-(
I do this because my repo is on a small USB key.   I don't want or need my entire history.
If I had a method for just truncating the history, I would use that.

If I were interested in keeping my history I would archive the current repository.
At some point later I could clone the original repository, copy over all the changes from
the new repo (let's assume I haven't done much (any) renaming or deleteing).   And then make one
big commit that would represent all the changes made in the new repo as a single commit in the
old repo.   Is it possible to merge the histories?   Maybe if I used a branch and then
deleted the objects I didn't need.  (I dont' know enough about git internals to start fooling around like that).

Comment: You could just use Dropbox for this use case instead. I did for many years.

Comment: For pure synchronization, try FreeFileSync or `rsync`, [as I explain in my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1271882/convert-ntfs-partition-to-ext4-how-to-copy-the-data/1464264#1464264). That being said, occasionally I use `git` for synchronization too, [as I explain for my `sync_git_repo_from_pc1_to_pc2.sh` tool here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/README_git-sync_repo_from_pc1_to_pc2.md), and in my other answer here: [Work on a remote project with Eclipse via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315754/4561887).

Answer (score 1):

Tried above methods, nothing worked in my case (where I accidently killed the git process during git push) so I finally had to delete the repo and clone it again and now the .git folder is of normal size.

Comment: I had to use the same solution because my disk was full (.git folder being > 90 GB) so I couldn't even run a repack or git gc!

Comment: try to command to delete  rm -rf .git/objects/pack/pack-*

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use BFG Repo Cleaner ([it is recommended by BitBucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/reduce-repository-size/) and much-much faster any other option):
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Also I have tried to use Steve Lorek's Solution and it also works :  https://web.archive.org/web/20190207210108/http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git fsck` for list files still exist but are dangling, then run `git prune` will delete them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple first step is to make a local clone of your local repo. That will give you a clean `.git` dir.

`git clone orig-local-repo new-local-repo`

That reduced my .git dir size from 1000 MB to 50 MB. Which was even more savings than running `git lfs prune`.

If you need more reduction after this, then try the other answers. But this is a quick first step to try.

P.S. Don't forget to set the remote repo in the `new-local-repo`, otherwise it will be pointing to your local repo.

`git remote set-url origin https://foo.git`