# git lfs "objects" taking a lot of disk space

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have a project with a lot of binaries (mostly pdfs) that I'm using git-lfs with.  The project is about 60mb but I found that my .git/lfs/objects director is about 500mb.  I presume these are cached versions of previous commits.  Is there a way to gracefully delete these (ie delete them without corrupting the state of git)?  The odds of me ever wanting previous versions of the files in LFS are near 0 now especially since the project is over.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found the [git-lfs man pages](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/tree/master/docs/man).  It turns out there is a `git lfs prune` command which does exactly what I needed:

```
C:\Path\to\project [master]> du -h -d 0
625M    .
C:\Path\to\project [master]> git lfs prune
* 101 local objects, 88 retained
Pruning 13 files, (393.8 MB)
* Deleted 13 files
C:\Path\to\project [master]> du -h -d 0
231M    .
```

Comment: Interesting, in my version of git-lfs no prune is mentioned in the man pages, but the command works! `git-lfs/1.5.6 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.7.4)`

Comment: I also wrote about this command in my answer here: [How to shrink your .git folder in your git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder/68554906#68554906)