# Git directory clean up

Tags: git, jenkins

The git repository directory on the test server is 1.1GB big.
How can I reduce the directory?

Approach.
Scripts are developed on my computer.
Uploaded to the Git repository by Jenkins to test the server to test.
The Git directory on the test server has grown to 1.1GB, which is the directory .git / objects.
How can I reduce it?

Can I simply delete the subdirectories of .git / objects?
Or is this handled by a git commands?

On the picture, schematic representation of the workings
[image]

greetings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to shrink the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder)

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research.

Answer (score 0):

This may help when doing git clone try shallow clone with some limited depth

```
git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/org/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=50 # timeout=10
```

that should reduce the size of the project

Answer (score 0):

My approach and my solution.
Log on the "test server".
Change to the directory */var/www/*. 
First of all, I did the following

```
       dh -hs .git
```

output **1.1GB**
then

```
        git count-objects -v
```

last command

```
        git repack -a -d --depth=500 --window=250
```

I followed the link from CodeCaster:  [how to shrink the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder)