# Reducing .git folder size after submodule addition

Tags: git

I have a git repository that has a .git folder that spans at 19GB. The folder used to be 4GB before adding a specific git submodule to the repository.
I need to reduce the size of the .git folder.

Based on [How to shrink the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder), I tried using

```
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250 -f
```

Both with and without the `-f` option but the .git folder seems not to badge and stay at 19GB. I also tried running the same result on the submodule folder which (as expected) had not effect.

I have avoided using the `git gc --aggressive --prune` option as it seems not to be recommended.

Is there any way I can reduce the size of the submodule data on the top .git repository?

Comment: 19GB are already in the remote? Or is just your local copy?

Comment: I believe it is on the remote as well