# How to resume `git lfs post-checkout` hook after failed `git checkout`

Tags: git, git-lfs

My `git lfs checkout` keeps failing at 97% complete while downloading 27 GB in 3 hours due to not enough disk space. Any way to resume it, rather than starting over once I free up some disk space?

---

I'm working in a monstrously huge `git` mono-repo on the order of 100 GB in size. we have a git post-checkout hook in `.git/hooks/post-checkout` which contains the following hook to run `git lfs` after each checkout:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs post-checkout "$@"
```

I just ran `git checkout main` and after literally 3 hrs of running and 27 GB of data downloaded through my internet connection, it failed because my disk was full, at about 97% complete through the `git lfs` post-checkout hook operation.

So, I cleared up some disk space.

Now, `git checkout main` fails with error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

So, I tried running `git lfs post-checkout main` (I don't even know if this is a reasonable command--I'm guessing here) manually, and it fails too, with:

> This should be run through Git's post-commit hook.  Run `git lfs update` to install it.

**Is there any way to resume my `git lfs` operation so I do NOT have to clear all 27 GB of data just downloaded and start downloading it all over again from scratch (via `git reset --hard && git clean -fd && git checkout main`)?**

Note that `git checkout main` had shown some errors like this as a result of the `git lfs` post-checkout hook operation:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    [list of tons of files]
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    [list of tons of files]
Aborting
0
```

Comment: Try `git reset --hard` and then `git checkout main` again.

Comment: @bk2204 that works, but `git reset --hard` deletes all 27 GB downloaded and makes `git lfs` start from scratch, downloading the entire thing again.

Comment: `git status` currently shows tens of thousands of files as "Changes not staged for commit".

Comment: Yes, Git-LFS is annoying like that. I don't actually use it and don't know what the right workaround is: you need to get it to start up the long-running filter and do the filtering of all the files that `git checkout` was in the middle of checking out. (The details will depend on your Git and Git-LFS vintage.) It's probably literally faster and easier to just re-run the entire 30 GB checkout.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I had is to comment out the last line in the `.git/hooks/post-checkout` dir so that it looks like this:

```sh
# git lfs post-checkout "$@"
```

Then, save the file and run `git checkout main`. When done, run `git lfs pull`, then uncomment the line above to return that file to normal. This way, since the `git checkout` *alone* takes like 10 minutes and checks out like 80000 files, at a minimum, that part will get done and pass before the `git lfs` part runs and takes forever (3+ hrs) and possibly crashes.

I'm not sure if that works or not, but anyway, I don't have an exact solution to my problem, so here's what I did:

1. `git checkout main` failed due to my disk running out of space. `git status` now shows thousands of files which are changed and unstaged. So, run the following to clear up your `git status` in preparation to run `git checkout` again:

   ```sh
   git status        # see that there are thousands of unstaged changes
   git reset --hard  # reset changed files back to how they are in `main`
   git clean -fd     # delete all unstaged files and directories
   git status        # this should now be clean
   ```
2. Reduce usage on your disk by deleting your bazel cache, if using the Bazel build system:

   ```sh
   df -h  # check current disk usage
   rm -rf ~/.cache/bazel  # delete Bazel build cache
   df -h  # ensure you have more space free now
   ```
3. Reduce the size of your `.git` folder to free up disk space. See my full answer here on this: [How to shrink the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613345/how-to-shrink-the-git-folder/68554906#68554906).

   ```sh
   time git lfs prune
   time git gc
   time git prune
   time git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
   ```
4. Now try the checkout again, *just letting it re-download the entire 30 GB or so over the course of 3+ hrs*. :( Oh well...at least it will pass now since I just freed up disk space by 1) reducing the size of my `.git` dir and 2) deleting my Bazel build cache:

   ```sh
   time git checkout main
   ```

Done.