# How to recover from git repack?

Tags: git, diskspace

I had not enough disk space and wished to [shrink my local git repo with a command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483112/258483)

```
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

I had repo size of 6G and free space of 8G.

During execution of this command disk space was depleted and command failed. Now I have zero free space i.e. situation turned worse. How to repair it without re-cloning repo?

Comment: Show the output of `git count-objects -v`. It helps to see what takes up the space.

Comment: all of git's database is stored within the directory `.git` at the root of your local repository. You can start by checking the size of that directory and copy it to another medium (another disk, a USB stick, a distant server ...) with enough space, and run your maintainance operations on that copy. Also : make a backup copy.