# How can I make/follow a release announcement feed on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket, release

On GitHub you can use a git tag to [publish a release announcement](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release) which will then appear on a release page [(example)](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases) and release feed [(example)](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases.atom). If a developer has done this, you can subscribe to the feed to receive notification of releases rather than all commits.

Is it possible to do this on Bitbucket (hg and/or git)?

(There is an additional option to include binaries / tarballs in GitHub release announcements. I am not concerned with that feature or any others beyond a feed with announcement entries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently (Q4 2014/Q1 2015).

Any feed issue is managed in "[notifications](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues?component=Notifications)".
The closest you have from feeds (for release or anyhting else) is:

- the [dashboard newsfeed](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Inbox+and+email+notifications) for commits
- The [event sources API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/events+Resources) (to help you detect events, and make your own feed)

---

Original answer, regarding the possibility to upload release files:

The [BitBucket FAQ on "repository/file/upload size?"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=273877699#Whatkindoflimitsdoyouhaveonrepository/file/uploadsize?-morelimitsinfo) does mention:

> Keep in mind Bitbucket is a code hosting service not a file sharing service. If a lot of your files are extremely large or if your files are binaries or executables, you should understand Git or Mercurial will not work well with them. You'll find that even locally your repository is barely usable. Moreover, Bitbucket can't display diffs on binaries.
>
> For binary or executable storage, we recommend you look into file hosting services  such as DropBox, rsync, rsnapshot, rdiff-backup, and so forth.
> Still not sure what to do? Review [this post on stackoverflow for more ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284669/6309).

Comment: that's good to know, but wasn't what I was after - I have edited my question to make it clearer I'm only after announcements, not binaries - if anything else could be fixed, please let me know - and thanks again anyhow