# How do I make a releases, builds, and/or snapshots with BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, release, snapshot

I would like to be able to make releases and builds for my game.
I know GitHub has releases, but I am using BitBucket instead.

Does anyone know how to make releases with BitBucket as like a checkpoint so I can just have the files documented for every update?

Comment: I used a "tag" to achieve some way of marking a commit as being the HEAD of a certain release, considering everything "behind" it to be part of that release, if that makes sense?

Comment: Not really the point of your question but migrating from one git host to the next is easy as `git remote add someName so://me:url && git push someName someBranchProbablyMaster` ...
Thought that was worth mentionning ...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

2022: [BCLOUD-11404](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-11404) shows this is still not implemented

---

2015: As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481025/6309), BitBucket doesn't support the GitHub-like release feature. [Its FAQ](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=273877699#Whatkindoflimitsdoyouhaveonrepository/file/uploadsize?-morelimitsinfo) still mention:

> For binary or executable storage, we recommend you look into file hosting services  such as DropBox, rsync, rsnapshot, rdiff-backup, and so forth.  Still not sure what to do? Review [this post on stackoverflow for more ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284669/6309).

For a BitBucket repo, you still have a [soft limit to 1GB and an hard limit to 2GB](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/05/30/repository-size-limits/).

Comment: Do you know another git services with this feature?

Comment: I've been hoping Bitbucket would improve with the Atlassian acquisition. But.. GitHub has been much more enjoyable in my experience.

Comment: @TJOlsen Yes, GitHub has benefited from Microsoft more, and is backed by Azure (See GitHub Actions)

Comment: why does ANYONE use bitbucket, it is literal garbage. lets remove ALL the features that github has shall we ;)

Comment: @jenkizenki Only good reason I know so gar: Bitbucket can be installed on your **own local server** which is extremely important for companies handling sensible software.

Comment: @JE_Muc Alas Bitbucket is "moving to the cloud", which is where software goes to die.

Answer (score 33):

BitBucket Pipelines allows automatic builds and the output can be pushed to BitBucket Downloads.

[BitBucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines)

[BitBucket Downloads](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2009/04/12/new-feature-downloads/)

[BitBucket Pipelines to BitBucket Downloads](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads-872124574.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but this seems to be somewhat resolved now (by 2022).

In the web interface for the repository, there is a left-hand side menu.  Towards the bottom of the list, there is an option 'Downloads'.  From there, on the initial tab, there is a button 'Add Files', which you can add zips, exes, etc.

Not quite the same, but good enough for me.

Comment: Had to give you credit for this response. Though, downloads has always been there.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a directory "releases" in my repository. In this directory I store my "tar.gz" files using [Git LFS](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs).